# What is better for fan: to be stopped at low load or to get spinned slowly at low load?

Tags: fan, cooling

What is better for fan's lifespan: if it stops oftenly (can be even 10-15 times per hour sometimes) or if it spins slowly? Thermals aren't a question, they are good either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work fine both ways, if the fan is pretty good product from a good vendor it should work just fine even under pressure. But if I have to choose I think sinned slowly is better than reactivating the fan 20 times per day for example

Comment: fan is piece of junk, and I have no choice it's laptop fan. It's just a question what will kill it in 1 year and what in 1,5 years.

Answer (score 0):

If your fan is good quality in a good machine, it can run at low speed forever. Going back 2 decades, I have never burnt out a fan that runs at low and only occasionally on high.  This is one big value in keeping CPU load reasonable (contributes to long fan life).